# How do I add String value in Hash Set if a string contains the same character in upper case and lower case?

Tags: java, collections

How do I add String value in Hash Set if a string contains the same character in upper case and lower case?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

set.add("Abc");
set.add("abc");

System.out.println("Size---"+set.size());
System.out.println(set);

}
```

OP::

Size---2
[abc, Abc]

Comment: You want set to contain only one string after that or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please find following solution. Your original value will remain same.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
String Str = "Abc";
String Str1 = "abc";
set.add("Abc");
if(!Str.equalsIgnoreCase("abc")) {
    set.add("abc");
}

System.out.println("Size---"+set.size());
System.out.println(set);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want the strings to be added to the hash set case-insensitive, then call `toLowerCase()` on strings prior to putting them in:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

set.add("Abc".toLowerCase());
set.add("abc".toLowerCase());

System.out.println("Size---"+set.size());
System.out.println(set);

}
```

This will produce a set of size 1, containing only "abc".

Comment: But in this case i will lost my original value

Comment: Yes, but that's unavoidable.  If you make two different values into the same value, at least one of them will have been lost.

Comment: You can use equalignorecase to check for case sensitive